# Parameters.ParamByname Doesn't accept string values Delphi

Tags: string, delphi, parameters

I have the following code

```
procedure TFrmMain.ComboBox1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin



 if Key = #13 then
 begin
  ADOQuery1.close;
  ADOQuery1.sql.Text := 'INSERT INTO palletweighttemp(TickCode,SchedID,BatchNo)values';
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add(' (:field1,(select SchedID from TicketBatch where TickCode =:field1),');
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('(select BatchNo from TicketBatch where TickCode =:field1))');
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('field1').DataType := ftString;
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('field1').Value := ComboBox1.Text;
  ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
       PopulateDBGrid;
        ComboBox1.SetFocus;
       end;

 end;
```

I Populate my comboBox using

```
procedure TFrmMain.PopulateBoxes();
begin
ComboBox1.SetFocus;

ComboBox1.Perform(WM_SYSKEYDOWN, VK_TAB, 0);

ComboBox1.clear;
ADOQuery1.sql.add
('select * from TicketBatch where isProcesed = 0 and TickCode is not null');
ADOQuery1.open;
ComboBox1.Text := '';
while not ADOQuery1.Eof do
begin
ComboBox1.Items.add(ADOQuery1.FieldByName('TickCode').AsString);
ADOQuery1.Next;
end;
 ADOQuery1.close;



 end;
```

If i press enter to run my Combobox1KeyPress procedure an error pops up that [image]

I'm assuming it's because its a needs a integer and currently is a string
Please assist

Comment: So, `TickCode` column is an `int` type? If so, do not define a parameter for it as string, not even think you'll be able to insert there the text value `'F105165'`. Is that value meant to be a hexadecimal numeral or you want to store into that column text values?

Comment: The vaule is a String type and it needs to be stored as a string

Comment: Run the project in debugger mode. At what line does it stop raising that error ?. Knowing that line will help you to determine the cause.

Comment: `TickCode` is clearly an `int`, and `F105165` is not an int. Is it really unclear to you what the problem is here? If the value is a string, and needs to be stored as a string, then change the column's datatype to one that supports a string (NVARCHAR, VARCHAR, etc.) and not an integer.

Comment: It's not obvious it's about `TickCode`. The other column(s) can differ in data types in those two tables.

Comment: @JohanDantuma That error message is a **SQL** error message. So no matter how much you want to believe `TickCode` is a string type, it ***most certainly is*** an int type on either the `PalletWeightTemp` or `TicketBatch` table or both. 1) The the data type(s) in the database as necessary. 2) Learn to pay attention to your error messages; there's no point in stubbornly ignoring what they tell you - it's the surest path to _**NOT** learning_.

Comment: @Craig, I agree with you, but who knows? An error saying e.g. _"PalletWeightTemp.SchedID does not match the TicketBatch.SchedID data type in the subquery <subquery>"_ would be far much more explicative (and I bet not that difficult to implement from the server side). In other words, are you sure it's the "main" query that is guilty here?

Comment: @Victoria Correct, the error could arise from a trigger on the table. So as you say in your answer, that would be the next thing to check.

Answer (score 3):

You must make sure the column data types match in both tables so as the query parameter data type matches the column data types in both tables. With your current code the tables need to be defined like:

> PalletWeightTemp.TickCode → TicketBatch.TickCode → (N)VARCHAR
>   PalletWeightTemp.SchedID → TicketBatch.SchedID → same data type
>   PalletWeightTemp.BatchNo → TicketBatch.BatchNo → same data type

Once you'll have it defined like that, the error message should disappear. If not, another possible source of this error I would focus on is an insertion trigger that contains a similar mismatching data type query.

One last note to the query itself - it can be simplified like this (it removes the redundant subquery):

```sql
INSERT INTO PalletWeightTemp
  (TickCode, SchedID, BatchNo)
SELECT
  :TickCode, SchedID, BatchNo
FROM
  TicketBatch WHERE TickCode = :TickCode
```

Comment: Very good answer, +1, considering the lack of important detail in the q.  Ideally, the OP should provide an MCVE in a case like this, but hopefully this will suffice to get him going.

Answer (score 0):

The  property "DataType" of ParamByName is not to be set by you. As the documentation from Embarcardero clearly states, this is set automatically when a value is assigned. Setting it yourself will only lead to strange errors.

You can use it to check for type and do your own error-handling etc. like:

```
IF  (ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('field1').DataType = ftInteger)
AND (not TRYSTRTOINT(ComboBox1.Text),myInt) then
  ShowMessage('invalid ticket code!');
```

As the other answeres stated, look into your table definitions, you will have a type mismatch there.